# Error in correlation, results missing for a variable

Tags: r

```
> # Create a simple DataFrame
> data <- data.frame(
+   Turtle = c("Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp4"),
+   Lake = c(3, 2, 6, 2),
+   River = c(12, 2, 9, 8),
+   Igapo = c(1, 3, 11, 1)
+ )
> # Display the DataFrame
> print(data)
  Turtle Lake River Igapo
1    Sp1    3    12     1
2    Sp2    2     2     3
3    Sp3    6     9    11
4    Sp4    2     8     1
> # Assuming your DataFrame is called 'data'
> species <- data$Turtle
> environments <- colnames(data)[2:4]  # Select environment columns
> # Initialize a matrix to store correlations
> correlations <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(species), ncol = length(environments))
> rownames(correlations) <- species
> colnames(correlations) <- environments
> # Calculate Pearson correlation for each combination
> for (i in 1:length(species)) {
+   for (j in 1:length(environments)) {
+     correlations[i, j] <- cor(data[[environments[j]]], data[[environments[i]]], method = "pearson")
+   }
+ }
Error in cor(data[[environments[j]]], data[[environments[i]]], method = "pearson") : 
  forneça conjuntamente 'x' e 'y' ou algo semelhante a uma matriz 'x'
> # Display the correlation matrix
> print(correlations)
         Lake      River      Igapo
Sp1 1.0000000 0.38844208 0.92465840
Sp2 0.3884421 1.00000000 0.01669684
Sp3 0.9246584 0.01669684 1.00000000
Sp4        NA         NA         NA
```

I would like to show the correlation for the Sp4 as well:

```
> print(correlations)
         Lake      River      Igapo
Sp1 1.0000000 0.38844208 0.92465840
Sp2 0.3884421 1.00000000 0.01669684
Sp3 0.9246584 0.01669684 1.00000000
Sp4        NA         NA         NA
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are a number of potential issues - it might help to clarify your goal first. It looks like you want to build a correlation matrix? Your sample data has 4 turtle species, with numbers representing 3 environments. So for a correlation between "Sp1" and "Lake" - what should that be? A correlation between which values and which values? Please give a concrete example for your use case, and I believe you can get better assistance.